# Notify the recyclerview item when it is onMoving without interruption

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've expandable row layouts in `RecyclerView`, normally they're expanded. 
Atteched `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` to the `RecyclerView` for moving the rows with `onMove()`. Everythings is right and moving the rows  correctly.

ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback:

```
@Override
public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {

    int fromPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
    int toPosition = target.getAdapterPosition();

    Collections.swap(adapter.getShelves(), fromPosition, toPosition);
    adapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);

    return true;
}

// Minifying the rows before the onMove is started:
@Override
public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
    adapter.minifyRow(position);
    return true;
}
```

It should minify the rows when long pressing, before onMoving() is started. Then should start the moving without any interrupting. The problem is starting dragging and minifiying the row when long press but interrupting the dragging at the moment. So it doesn't dragging or moving the row. How to simulate onMove with notify?

In adapter class:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {    
    boolean rowIsExpanded = rows.get(position).isExpanded();
    if(rowIsExpanded){
        holder.rowLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.rowLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }   
}

public void minifyRow(boolean situation, int adapterPos){
    RowModel row = rows.get(adapterPos);
    row.setExpanded(situation);
    notifyItemChanged(adapterPos);
}
```

Comment: Could you show your code when you handle onLongPress, it calls inside ViewHolder?

Comment: Handling long press in `isLongPressDragEnabled()` with `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback`, no the other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call `adapter.minifyRow(position);` inside `isLongPressDragEnabled` it only flags to check your adapter enable long-press or not. You should override `onSelectedChanged`. Remove method in `isLongPressDragEnabled` and Try this

```
    @Override
    public void onSelectedChanged(@Nullable RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
        if (viewHolder != null && actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG) {
            ((YourViewHolder)viewHolder).rowLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, worked but how to reach all of viewHolder.rowLayouts?

Comment: What do you mean to reach all? You mean elements inside row layout right? actually you can access your holder it means if you find view in your holder, it can get directly

Comment: No, I mean the rowLayout inside your code for current position item on RecyclerView, how to reach the other items' rowLayout's?

Comment: for the current position, you can call viewHolder.getAdapterPostion()